# Email queue implementation with Java

Tags: java, mysql, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have a DB whose columns are:

```
| from_email | to_email | subject | body | processed(Y/N) |
```

Now I want to implement a system in Java that will access this DB for not processed, send the mail **(I'm using fakeSMTP for testing)**   and set it as processed.

It works fine enough, although I have yet to add any threading.

But the problem is to speed up the procedure it might be deployed over more than one server, in that case how can I ensure no mail gets sent twice?

How can it be made faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be the solution to your problem:

1. Each server should have a unique id
2. Add the server_id with default value of `null` to your `mails` table
3. When a server intends to send a mail, run a query, like:

   `update mails
   set server_id = <your server_id>
   where (server_id is null) and (<your other criteria>)`
4. After you processed the `update`, select the row and if `server_id` has the expected value (no concurrency issue occurred), then process it
5. If a record's `server_id` is not `null`, then its processing has been already started. If its `server_id` is not null and its `processed` is `Y`, then it has been processed.

Comment: whai if i don't have a server id?
right now i'm testing on my system, so there is no way to get a server id.

now, i can pass random values as id; but not sure how that will turn out in real scenario.

Comment: If you don't have a server_id, then create one. A server should have such a setting and if that does not have a value, generate one and store into the database, so you will not have duplicated server ids. So, the solution for the problem of not having server ids is: create server ids.

Comment: but if i use threads, in that case using server id won't solve the problem.
I still have to differentiate between them.

Comment: You can add a thread id as well. If you are using separate threads on separate servers, you can have both server id and thread id and use both of them.

Comment: Thanks @Lajos. 
This is certainly the better way.